# Variant Join in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am converting a spreadsheet that had over 80 Sumifs for output.

For a query, I can join 2 tables, but they depend on 6-8 factors that aren't consistent, hence, the sumifs.

I've been successful with right joins in some instances, but most of the time I have to piece meal all of the conditions.

One of my approaches is to write a function like this:

```
Public Function DetermineCOB_ID(strFund As String, strType As String, strMDEP As String, _
strTier1 As String, strAirGround As Variant, strAcctType As String) As Integer

    If strFund = "A82AB" And strType = "Base" And strTier1 = "2 BCT" And strMDEP = "W25D" And strAcctType = "Subordinate_Cmds" Then
        DetermineCOB_ID = 1
    ElseIf strFund = "A82AC" And strType = "Base" And strMDEP = "W25D" And strAcctType = "Subordinate_Cmds" Then
        DetermineCOB_ID = 2
    ElseIf strFund = "A82AD" And strType = "Base" And strMDEP = "W25D" And strAirGround = "Ground" And strAcctType = "Subordinate_Cmds" Then
        DetermineCOB_ID = 3
    Else
        DetermineCOB_ID = 0
    End If


End Function
```

But I will have to write 80 separate ElseIf statements.

I'd like to hook up my logic to a control table that the user can change the factors that determine the values.

This would somehow involve a 'variant' join everywhere there is a join where one is not required.  I hope I am making sense.

Is there another approach to solving this problem?

Comment: It's very difficult to say without seeing the schema and your desired results. My gut tells me that your table schema is the real problem here though since you have 80 different ways to join two tables based on values in the records within those tables. That just sounds really nasty.

Comment: You could create a table with your 80 options, but as @JNevill suggests, this is very indicative of a poor schema.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am working with a back end that leaves a lot to be desired.  In the interim, I'm probing for alternate solutions.   Do you know a way to make a join respond like a variant variable i.e so it can work with null values.  I've tried outer joins but it doesn't really work.